# trying to create a dropdown menu but it is not working for the javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

> This is what it looks like when cliked on

[image]

> This is the expectation when clicked on what i used to display this is the :hover event but i want it clickable
>   [image]

Please help if anything possable as soon as you can to fix the Javascript coding

```js
var content = document.getElementById("settingsBar");
var button = document.getElementById("show-more");

button.onclick = function() {
  if (content.className == "drop") {
    content.className = "";
  } else {
    content.className = "drop";
  }
};
```

```css
#settingsBar {
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: #000;
  max-height: 56px;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.7s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.7s;
  transition: all 0.7s;
}
#settingsBar.drop {
  max-height: 1000px;
  color: #fff;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.7s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.7s;
  transition: all 0.7s;
}
#show-more i {
  padding-left: 48%;
  padding-top: 15px;
  color: #fff;
  -webkit-transition: color 0.7s;
  -moz-transition: color 0.7s;
  transition: color 0.7s;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<div id="settingsBar">
  <a href="#" id="show-more"><i class="material-icons large">settings</i></a>
  <br/>
  <iframe src="http://www.pigigram.com/account_settings.php" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" width="100%"></iframe>
</div>
```

> Basicly What i want is to have it open the content to display the iframe and allow them to use the settings

Comment: Could you add a codepen/fiddle/plunkr/whatever to demonstrate your issue?

Comment: my issue is i cant open the element its clickable but dosnt want to expand the div to display the iframe that lies in it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
button.onclick = fucntion(); {
```

You misspelled the word function

Comment: even though i changed the spelling it still doesn't work

Comment: @TheLiveitup34 - are you using Bootstrap?

Comment: @Landslyde no im not im using custom code for my who website and what it should do when you click on the cog is that it should add the varible of .drop to the id and make it drop down and overlay with 1000px but it doesnt want to interact with the <a> for the cog